# How to log an index of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This question is more of a *why* does this particular code work this way than a *how* can I make this code work this way.

Im going through the codecademy tutorials for JavaScript and I came across a lesson that I conceptually can make use of in my own code because I can see the pattern of this particular code - but it doesn't make sense why this code works this way.

Below is an example:

```
let myArray = ['First','Second','Third'];
var last = myArray[myArray.length - 1];
console.log(last);
```

The console displays "Third" when running the above code. I know the JavaScript language is a "zero indexed" language and I know that "first" in this array would be position "0" counting from left to right but my question is even if we start at "0" and count every item; 0 then 1 then 2; shouldn't the console log "Second"
instead of "Third"? Or does the method of "length" in JavaScript ignore the "0" based indexing system and actually start counting at "1"; in witch case the answer should ***STILL*** be "Second" and not "Third"... No matter how my brain adds this up I keep getting "Second" instead of "Third" in my mind even though the output is "third" on the console...

Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: knowing that `myArray.length - 1 == 2` ... now what do you think ... the length is the length, which is 3 ... not 2, because there are 3 elements ... the index is zero based, the length is ... well, the length

Comment: index : `0, 1, 2` still has length of `3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code out and it will help. This stuff was tricky for me too. It's just using a variable and calculating it at the same time.

```
let myArray = ['First','Second','Third'];
var last = myArray[myArray.length - 1];
console.log(last);
```

First, we have to note that `myArray.length` is 3 because there are 3 items in it.

Second, now we can re-analyze this but exchange `myArray.length` with 3:

```
myArray[3 - 1]
```

Now, you can see it is simply calculating 3-1, which is 2, so the code is identical to:

```
myArray[2] // which returns the item at position 2 (starting from 0), [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: ok I see, yes that makes perfect sense, I think my problem was i was conceptually trying to get an answer without first breaking it into two separate steps (like your example), Now i see it clearly. THANKYOU

Comment: It's also tricky sometimes to see object properties similar to this. You might see `object.name`, or you might see `object['name']` and where it gets tricky is sometimes you see variables in there, like `object[something1 + something2]` which is "concatenating" (ie: smashing two things together), so it's actually `object.something1something2`. Those typically show up as `object['something' + i]` (where `i` is an iterator number that goes up).

Comment: Note you can also use `myArray.indexOf('Third')` to find the position of the thing you want.

Answer (score 2):

`array.length` is a number of items in it, there are 3 items. But array indexes starts from 0 and the last index will be 2, not 3. So if you want to get array element using `array.length`, you need to decrease this length by 1 if you want to get the last element, by 2 if you want to get the previous one and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Array.length returns the **number of items** in an array. It has no bearing on the index.

Length - 1 will always be the final index in array though, simply because arrays are 0 indexed in practice.